# Use WCF class library in application

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am new to WCF and I don't really understand the puropose of a WCF class library. (it does not look like a library to me it launches a program when I run my application) I have created a WPF application with a reference to my WCF service library. Everything works great under development. When I launch my application from visual studio the service get's hosted automatically by visual studio.

Now let's say I am ready to deploy. If I launch the application from outside visual studio then the service will not run. How do I start the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF service class cannot exist in a void. You need to host and there are a couple of option for **[Hosting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729846.aspx)**.

In Visual Studio, there was two main template for WCF, **WCF Service Application** and **WCF Service Library**. Depend on your need, choose which template will be good for your project. If you want Self Hosting, better choose WCF Service Library template. (*You need to write Hosting Service/Application*). If you want to Host in IIS, better choose WCF Service Application.

And check this Tutorial for self hosting.

http://wcftutorial.net/WCF-Self-Hosting.aspx